# Dictionary keys as pandas column labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

Say I have a dictionary `d`. And I want to create a pandas `DataFrame`, with all keys in `d` as column labels. And the number of rows lets say is `n`. How would I go about this?

example

```
n = 4
d = {'what': 5, 'where': 10, 'who': 66}
```

I want something like this

```
what where who
0     0     0
0     0     0 
0     0     0
0     0     0
```

Comment: I updated the question, just to have the dictionary keys as labels only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
n = 4
d = {'what': 5, 'where': 10, 'who': 66}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=0, columns=d, index=range(n))

#    what  where  who
# 0     0      0    0
# 1     0      0    0
# 2     0      0    0
# 3     0      0    0
```

Comment: This is it. I had something similar but left out the range. And the data was being interpreted as the dictionary values.